# Using the matrix of adjacency to find number of paths (not walks)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am well aware that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then $A^n=a^{(n)}_{ij}$ counts the number of walks of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.
Is there a way to modify this so that you end up with a matrix that counts the **paths** between vertices?

For me a path is a walk that doesn't repeat vertices.

This would also have interesting consequences as being able to count the number of n-cycles in a graph, etc.

Has anyone thought of this before? I haven't been able to find literature concerning this.

---

Here's what I've thought so far, I'm trying to do it recursively:

1. Start with $A$, the adjacency matrix of a graph. Then $a_{ij}$ is the number of paths of length 1 from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. Notice there aren't any walks that aren't paths.
2. Multiply by $A$ to get $A^2$. The only walks that aren't paths are on the diagonal (these are walks of the type $v_i v_j v_i$). We get rid of them by considering $A^2-diag(A^2)$. Here $diag(A^2)$ means leaving the diagonal as it is and making every off-diagonal entry $0$ (don't know if there's standard notation fot that).
3. Multiply by $A$ to get $A(A^2-diag(A^2))$. Now, this matrix counts how many walks there are between two vertices that start with a path of lentgh 2. That means we have paths of the type $v_i v_j v_k v_j$ which we don´t want to count.
   Notice that for each path of lentgh one (let's say the edge $v_i v_j$) we have $deg(v_j)-1$ paths that we don't want. Therefore, we have to subtract $A\circ B$ where $B$ is the matrix defined by $b_{ij}=deg(v_j)-1$ and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product (pointwise product).
4. Finally, $A(A^2-diag(A^2))-A\circ B$ gives us the number of paths from a vertex to the other.

---

Following this idea I conjectured that in general, if $\tilde{A_n}$ is the matrix that counts paths of length $n$, then **$$\tilde{A_n} = A(\tilde{A_{n-1}})-(A^{n-2}-diag(A^{n-2}))\circ B$$**

Edit: This is not correct as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: (not certain) I don't think you've accounted for $3,4,...-$cycles.

Comment: Have you tested this for simple examples (like small regular graphs)?

Comment: Not too many examples, but I have and it's worked.

Comment: The very fact that you could use this to count Hamiltonian paths tells us that there is no known efficient way to do it!

Comment: It was too good to be true sadly

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $A$ has $n-1$ vertices, then ${\overline A}_{n-1}=0$, but your conjectured formula doesn't give ${\overline A}_n=0$.

Comment: You're right. I think I failed to consider some things. I'm guessing this problem is way more complicated than i thought. Got any thoughts on it?

Comment: Sorry, I also came to the conclusion that it's a hard problem. Maybe adjacency matrices are the wrong data structure for counting paths.